# Change input value inside TD using row and column index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery so please bear with me.

I have a table that has columns quantity, price, and amount.
The amount column should be updated whenever there are changes in either quantity or price.

So far, here's my jquery event:

```
$('input.qtyPrice').on('change',function() {

   var rowIndex =  $(this).parent().parent().index();

    console.log($('#tableItems tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(4));
```

})

This writes the console `[prevObject: o.fn.init[0], context: document, jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, selector: ""…]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: o.fn.init[0]__proto__: o[0]`

I took that answer from another question here in Stackoverflow. 
My problem is, I can't seem to access the INPUT element (amount) inside the TD. 
[image]
Sorry for my English. I appreciate your inputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to access the rowIndex, you can directly find the amount like

```
$('input.qtyPrice').on('change', function () {

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    $tr.find('td:nth-child(5) input').val('updated')
})
```

Comment: That is a lot simpler than what I thought. 
Here's my final code for the event: 
`var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var price = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3) input').val();
                var qty = $tr.find('td:nth-child(4) input').val();
                var amount = price * qty;                                            
                $tr.find('td:nth-child(5) input').val(amount)`

Thank you :)